# Proof by shifting down the upper limit in Pascal's identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I found the following formula at the end of the first chapter of [Probability: For the Enthusiastic Beginner by David Morin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJSHWCX):

$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-2}{k-1} + \binom{n-3}{k-1} + \cdots + \binom{k+1}{k-1} + \binom{k}{k-1} + \binom{k-1}{k-1}$$

As an exercise I decided to prove it.

Here is what I did:

First I wrote down the definition of Pascal's identity:

$$\binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} \implies \binom{n-1}{k-1} = \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-1}{k}$$

Looking at the above-mentioned definition we can see that in fact by rewriting Pascal's identity successively and by decreasing each time the value of $n$ by $1$ until $n$ becomes $k-1$ we can build at the end the very same formula we want to prove, that is,

\begin{alignat*}{4}
  & \text{Pascal's identity} &&\implies  \binom{n-1}{k-1} &&= \binom{n}{k} &&- \binom{n-1}{k} \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{n-2}{k-1} &&= \binom{n-1}{k} &&- \binom{n-2}{k} \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{n-3}{k-1} &&= \binom{n-2}{k} &&- \binom{n-3}{k} \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{n-4}{k-1} &&= \binom{n-3}{k} &&- \binom{n-4}{k} \\[5pt]
  & && \vdots && \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{k+2}{k-1} &&= \binom{k+3}{k} &&- \binom{k+2}{k} \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{k+1}{k-1} &&= \binom{k+2}{k} &&- \binom{k+1}{k} \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{k}{k-1} &&= \binom{k+1}{k} &&- \binom{k+1}{k} \\[5pt]
  & \text{Reduce $n$ by $1$ in the above line} &&\implies  \binom{k-1}{k-1} &&= \binom{k}{k} &&- \binom{k-1}{k}
\end{alignat*}
Now if we add the left side and right side of the above identities we obtain:
$$\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1}\binom{i}{k-1} = \binom{n}{k} - \binom{k-1}{k}$$
Given that by definition $\binom{k-1}{k} = 0$ we can say:
$$\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1}\binom{i}{k-1} = \binom{n}{k}$$

Which is what we wanted to prove.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: your solution is correct

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity